# jaspersoft adhoc handling multi user edit mode request

Tags: jasperserver, adhoc

I am using Jaspersoft Ad Hoc crosstab and I have integrated it in to my existing web site using iframes.

My major concern over here is for user who has edit access on it in order to do analysis on the available data.

Once use saves the analysis, default view of the pre-generated adhoc updates by the existing once.

What I want is that, whenever user login in to my site, the editing he does on the adhoc should be visible to him only even if he saved the edits.

Suggest good way to achieve it,

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Ad Hoc View as read-only for certain users, they won't be able to make changes on your View.

Right-click on the Ad Hoc View, select "Permissions...", then change to something like "Read Only" for the relevant Role(s), or the User(s) directly.

When they open it, make changes and try to save, it will prompt them to save to a different location or with a different name, depending on the folder permissions.

I hope this helps!

[image]